# Are allergies due to memory T cells for benign antigens?

Tags: immune-system, allergy

If I understand correctly, the immune system reacts to infections by priming virgin helper T cells for the particular antigens exposed on the surface of the invader, leaving some memory T cells trained to trigger an attack on that antigen.

Am I correct in assuming that this same process can occur with benign allergens like fur, tree nuts and so on, to create memory T cells for these benign antigens, triggering an immune response on re-exposure? For example, exposure to soy at some point early in life resulting in creation of soy-adapted memory T cells, which trigger an immune reaction to soy upon re-exposure by eating it?